# Splitting specific information in one excel cell to several others

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to find a way to split some data on excel: e.g.
If a cell has the following in:  `LWPO0001653/1654/1742/1876/241`
All of the info after the `/` should be `LWPO000...` with that number.

Is there anyway of separating them out and adding in the `LWPO000`in? So they come out as `LWPO0001653
LWPO0001654`
etc etc

I could do manually yes, but i have thousands to do so would take a long time.

Appreciate your help!

Comment: I can't think of a formula that would do this, but it would be pretty easy with VBA.

Comment: Is it always the first 7 characters then everything split with a "/". If not, how would you identify the bit that gets repeated?

Comment: Thanks Kevin, problem being i have never used VBA & have no idea how!

Comment: JNevill, yes the first 7 characters are always that, and unfortunately its all been entered in a rather annoying way. beginning to think think manually doing it could be the only way.

Comment: @EdwardSemprini - See an example of how to do below with a macro

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using Excel Formulas.

With your original string in A1, and assuming the first seven characters are the one's that get repeated, then:

```
B1:  =LEFT($A1,FIND("/",$A1)-1)
C1:  =IF(LEN($A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A1,"/",""))< COLUMNS($A:A),"",LEFT($A1,7)&TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(MID($A1,8,99),"/",REPT(" ",99)),(COLUMNS($A:A))*99,99)))
```

Select C1 and fill right as far as required.  Then Fill down from Row 1

**EDIT:** For a VBA solution, try this code.  It assumes the source data is in column A, and puts the results adjacent starting in Column B (easily changed if necessary).  It works using arrays within VBA, as doing multiple worksheet read/writes can slow things down.  It will handle different numbers of splits in the various cells, although could be shortened if we knew the number of splits was always the same.

---

```
Option Explicit
Sub SplitSlash()
    Dim vSrc As Variant
    Dim rRes As Range, vRes() As Variant
    Dim sFirst7 As String
    Dim V As Variant
    Dim COL As Collection
    Dim I As Long, J As Long
    Dim lMaxColCount As Long

Set rRes = Range("B1")  'Set to A1 to overwrite
vSrc = Range("a1", Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))

'If only a single cell, vSrc won't be an array, so change it
If Not IsArray(vSrc) Then
    ReDim vSrc(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
    vSrc(1, 1) = Range("a1")
End If

'use collection since number of columns can vary
Set COL = New Collection
For I = 1 To UBound(vSrc)
    sFirst7 = Left(vSrc(I, 1), 7)
    V = Split(vSrc(I, 1), "/")
    For J = 1 To UBound(V)
        V(J) = sFirst7 & V(J)
    Next J
    lMaxColCount = IIf(lMaxColCount < UBound(V), UBound(V), lMaxColCount)
    COL.Add V
Next I

'Results array
ReDim vRes(1 To COL.Count, 1 To lMaxColCount + 1)
For I = 1 To UBound(vRes, 1)
    For J = 0 To UBound(COL(I))
        vRes(I, J + 1) = COL(I)(J)
    Next J
Next I

'Write results to sheet
Set rRes = rRes.Resize(UBound(vRes, 1), UBound(vRes, 2))
With rRes
    .EntireColumn.Clear
    .Value = vRes
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With

End Sub
```

---

Comment: C@Kevin Code is good, and might even be faster depending on the number of entries.  Do all the entries have the same number of segments?

Answer (score 1):

I'm clearly missing the point :-) but anyway, in B1 and copied down to suit:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/","/"&LEFT(A1,7))
```

Select ColumnB, Copy and Paste Special, Values over the top.
Apply Text to Columns to ColumnB, Delimited, with `/` as the delimiter.

Comment: After you do that, I think the OP wants to have the first seven characters prepended to each "split"

Comment: Excellent and much simpler than my formula

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of ways to solve this. The quickest is probably:

Assuming that the data is in column A:

1. Highlight the column, go to Data>>Text To Columns
2. Choose "Delimited" and in the "Other" box, put `/`
3. Click ok. You'll have your data split into multiple cells
4. Insert a column at B and put in the formula `=Left(A1, 7)`
5. Insert a column at C and pit in formula =`Right(A1, Length(A1)-7)`
6. You'll now have Column B with your first 7 characters, and columns B,C,D,E,F, etc.. with the last little bit. You can concatenate the values back together for each column you have with `=Concatenate(B1,C1)`, `=Concatenate(B1,D1)`, etc..

A quick VBa, which does nearly the same thing that @Kevin's does as well. I wrote it before I saw his answer, and I hate to throw away work ;)

```
Sub breakUpCell()
    Dim rngInput As Range, rngInputCell As Range
    Dim intColumn As Integer
    Dim arrInput() As String
    Dim strStart As String
    Dim strEnd As Variant

    'Set the range for the list of values (Assuming Sheet1 and A1 is the start)
    Set rngInput = Sheet1.Range("A1").Resize(Sheet1.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row)

    'Loop through each cell in the range
    For Each rngInputCell In rngInput

        'Split up the values after the first 7 characters using "/" as the delimiter
        arrInput = Split(Right(rngInputCell.Value, Len(rngInputCell.Value) - 7), "/")

        'grab the first 7 characters
        strStart = Left(rngInputCell.Value, 7)

        'We'll be writing out the values starting in column 2 (B)
        intColumn = 2

        'Loop through each split up value and assign to strEnd
        For Each strEnd In arrInput

            'Write the concatenated value out starting at column B in the same row as rngInputCell
            Sheet1.Cells(rngInputCell.Row, intColumn).Value = strStart & strEnd

            'Head to the next column (C, then D, then E, etc)
            intColumn = intColumn + 1

        Next strEnd

    Next rngInputCell
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks JNevill, Will give these a go when back in work tomorrow. Appreciate your's & Kevins help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it with a macro:

This is what is happening:

1) Set range to process
2) Loop through each cell in range and check it isn't blank
3) If the cell contains the slash character then split it and process
4) Skip the first record and concatenate "LWPO000" plus the current string to adjacent cells.

```
Sub CreateLWPO()

On Error Resume Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim theRange
Dim cellValue
Dim offset As Integer
Dim fields

'set the range of cells to be processed here
Set theRange = range("A1:A50")

'loop through each cell and if not blank process
For Each c In theRange

    offset = 0 'this will be used to offset each item found 1 cell to the right (change this number to this first column to be populated)
    If c.Value <> "" Then
        cellValue = c.Value

        If InStr(cellValue, "/") > 0 Then

          fields = Split(cellValue, "/")

          For i = 1 To UBound(fields)

            offset = offset + 1
            cellValue = "LWPO000" & fields(i)
            'if you need to pad the number of zeros based on length do this and comment the line above
            'cellValue = "LWPO" & Right$(String(7, "0") & fields(i), 7)
            c.offset(0, offset).Value = cellValue

          Next i

        End If

    End If
    Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```